# How do i rotate two lines independent of each other's axes in JOGL?

Tags: java, graphics, jogl

Given below is the code for two lines i created using JOGL. One of the lines in along the x axis, whereas the other, z. When i execute the code below, the line along the x axis rotates about the z axis as expected, however, the line along the z axis, doesn't just rotate about the x axis, it also unexpectedly rotates about the z axis(it's own axis). How do i prevent this from happening?

```
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable){

    final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glRotatef(rtri, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);//rotation about z axis
    gl.glBegin (GL2.GL_LINES);
    gl.glColor3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );   
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.50f, 0.0f, 0);//vertex 1 of line 1
        gl.glVertex3f(0.50f, 0.0f, 0);//vertex 2 of line 1
        gl.glEnd();
        gl.glFlush();

    gl.glRotatef(rtri, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);//rotation about x axis
    gl.glBegin (GL2.GL_LINES);
    gl.glColor3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );   
        gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 0, 0.5f);//vertex 1 of line 2
        gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 0, -0.5f);//vertex 2 of line 2
        gl.glEnd();
        gl.glFlush();

    rtri+=0.30f;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glRotate` makes changes to the currently active matrix, that is then multiplied with the vertex vectors. `glLoadIdentity` resets this matrix. If you want the second line to rotate completely independent, you just have to reset it again after drawing the first line:

```
gl.glLoadIdentity(); // reset matrix

gl.glRotatef(rtri, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // change matrix
// draw a line...

gl.glLoadIdentity(); // reset matrix, ... again    

gl.glRotatef(rtri, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // change matrix
// draw a line...
```